# Compass Error When Compiling Individual Stylesheets: "Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory"

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

I am having trouble compiling individual stylesheets using Compass. I am able to use `compass compile` to do all the files, and `compass watch` to monitor for changes. But when I try to assign a particular file to `compass compile`, I get get following error:

> Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory

My directory structure:

```
project root
- util
-- compass
--- config.rb
- www
-- css
--- [destination for .css files]
-- sass
--- [.scss files]
```

My config.rb:

```
project_type = :stand_alone

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
project_path = "../../"
http_path = "www"               # The path to the project when running within the web server.
css_dir = "www/css"         # relative to project_path
sass_dir = "www/sass"       # relative to project_path
images_dir = "www/images"   # relative to project_path
javascripts_dir = "www/js"  # relative to project_path

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true

# generate sourcemaps
sourcemap = true
```

The following work fine when run from the `/util/compass` folder:

```
compass compile
compass watch
```

These do not work:

```
compass compile builder.scss
compass compile ../../www/sass/builder.scss
compass compile www/sass/builder.scss
```

and cause the error which presumably means the scss file cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but at least gets you going. Probably this is caused by some bug in compass which leads to invalid `sass_path`. So set the `sass_path` manually like this:

```
project_type = :stand_alone

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
project_path = "../../"
http_path = "www"               # The path to the project when running within the web server.
css_dir = "www/css"         # relative to project_path
sass_dir = "www/sass"       # relative to project_path
sass_path = File.expand_path(File.join(project_path, sass_dir))
images_dir = "www/images"   # relative to project_path
javascripts_dir = "www/js"  # relative to project_path

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true

# generate sourcemaps
sourcemap = true
```

And then you should be able to build individual sass files by using command `compass compile ../../www/sass/builder.scss`